Local Core Data Backup/Restore iCloud conflict “ Told to tear down with reason: Stores Changed”
I have a backup / restore function for Core Data defined like this:
import CoreData
import FirebaseCrashlytics
import Foundation

extension NSPersistentCloudKitContainer {
    enum CopyPersistentStoreErrors: Error {
        case invalidDestination(String)
        case destinationError(String)
        case destinationNotRemoved(String)
        case copyStoreError(String)
        case invalidSource(String)
    }
    
    func restorePersistentStore(from backupURL: URL) throws {
        guard backupURL.isFileURL else {
            throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.invalidSource("Backup URL must be a file URL")
        }
        
        var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: backupURL.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
            if !isDirectory.boolValue {
                throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.invalidSource("Source URL must be a directory")
            }
        } else {
            throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.invalidSource("Source URL must exist")
        }
        
        for persistentStoreDescription in persistentStoreDescriptions {
            guard let loadedStoreURL = persistentStoreDescription.url else {
                continue
            }
            let backupStoreURL = backupURL.appendingPathComponent(loadedStoreURL.lastPathComponent)
            guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: backupStoreURL.path) else {
                throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.invalidSource("Missing backup store for \(backupStoreURL)")
            }
            do {
                var storeOptions = persistentStoreDescription.options
                storeOptions.updateValue(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
                let configurationName = persistentStoreDescription.configuration
                let storeType = persistentStoreDescription.type
                
                // Replace the current store with the backup copy. This has a side effect of removing the current store from the Core Data stack.
                // When restoring, it's necessary to use the current persistent store coordinator.
                try persistentStoreCoordinator.replacePersistentStore(at: loadedStoreURL, destinationOptions: storeOptions, withPersistentStoreFrom: backupStoreURL, sourceOptions: storeOptions, ofType: storeType)
                // Add the persistent store at the same location we've been using, because it was removed in the previous step.
                try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: storeType, configurationName: configurationName, at: loadedStoreURL, options: storeOptions)
            } catch {
                Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
                throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.copyStoreError("Could not restore: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
 
    func copyPersistentStores(to destinationURL: URL, overwriting: Bool = false) throws {
        guard destinationURL.isFileURL else {
            throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.invalidDestination("Destination URL must be a file URL")
        }
        
        var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
        if !overwriting, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
            if !isDirectory.boolValue {
                throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.invalidDestination("Destination URL must be a directory")
            }
 
        }

        if overwriting, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
            } catch {
                Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
                throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.destinationNotRemoved("Can't overwrite destination at \(destinationURL)")
            }
        }
        
        // Create the destination directory
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: destinationURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
            throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.destinationError("Could not create destination directory at \(destinationURL)")
        }
        
        for persistentStoreDescription in persistentStoreDescriptions {
            guard let storeURL = persistentStoreDescription.url else {
                continue
            }
            guard persistentStoreDescription.type != NSInMemoryStoreType else {
                continue
            }
            let destinationStoreURL = destinationURL.appendingPathComponent(storeURL.lastPathComponent)
            
            if !overwriting, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationStoreURL.path) {
                // If the destination exists, the replacePersistentStore call will update it in place. That's fine unless we're not overwriting.
                throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.destinationError("Destination already exists at \(destinationStoreURL)")
            }
            do {
                // Replace an existing backup, if any, with a new one with the same options and type. This doesn't affect the current Core Data stack.
                // The function name says "replace", but it works if there's nothing at the destination yet. In that case it creates a new persistent store.
                // Note that for backup, it doesn't matter if the persistent store coordinator is the one currently in use or a different one. It could be a class function, for this use.
                try persistentStoreCoordinator.replacePersistentStore(at: destinationStoreURL, destinationOptions: persistentStoreDescription.options, withPersistentStoreFrom: storeURL, sourceOptions: persistentStoreDescription.options, type: .sqlite)
            } catch {
                Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
                throw CopyPersistentStoreErrors.copyStoreError("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}


Backup and restore function works as expected locally. However when used with CloudKit, I get the following error in console and all the data is lost after restart and overridden by data stored in iCloud:
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate tearDown:]_block_invoke(808): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960>: Told to tear down with reason: Stores Changed

Followed by:

error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate recoverFromError:](2302): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960> - Attempting recovery from error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134404 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
    "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134407 \"Request 'ECA8B22F-4F97-4D7E-B6B9-D61CC5F2C4D9' was cancelled because the store was removed from the coordinator.\"

CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate resetAfterError:andKeepContainer:](605): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960> - resetting internal state after error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134404 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedImportWithLabel:activity:voucher:completionHandler:]_block_invoke(3633): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960> - Finished automatic import - SandboxImport - with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x301cb1650> storeIdentifier: 2A4E461C-6CBD-4EB1-8C3B-C8487E191315 success: 0 madeChanges: 1 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134410 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x301eef420 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134404 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest](3535): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960>: Checking for pending requests.

CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate resetAfterError:andKeepContainer:](605): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960> - resetting internal state after error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134404 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedImportWithLabel:activity:voucher:completionHandler:]_block_invoke(3633): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960> - Finished automatic import - SandboxImport - with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x301cb1650> storeIdentifier: 2A4E461C-6CBD-4EB1-8C3B-C8487E191315 success: 0 madeChanges: 1 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134410 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x301eef420 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134404 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest](3535): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x302f9c960>: Checking for pending requests.

I am wondering what step am I missing in the restorePersistentStore function to tell iCloud to use the newly restored persistent store data?

I would like to share the answer from Apple DTS.
“When using a Core Data + CloudKit store, Core Data maintains the state of the synchronization between the Core Data store and the CloudKit database. When you replace the store with a new one, Core Data loses the state, and hence doesn’t know how to synchronize the new store with the associated CloudKit database.
To use a backup store as the new truth, you need to remove all the data in CloudKit, and re-create the whole data set so it is synchronized to CloudKit.
Alternatively, if you can manage to know the changes between the current store and the backup one, applying the changes to the current store will work.”
It was suggested to submit a feedback to Core Data team to consider as API request. It is under FB13816791
